# Can a single git repository release multiple ROS stacks?

Tags: ros, git, rosinstall, ros-release, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am setting up a repository which will contain several ROS stacks. I want `rosinstall` and `ros_release` to manage each stack separately.  I know how to do it with `svn`, but `git` seems to force the whole repository to be managed as a unit.

- Is there a way to use `git` that meets these requirements?
- Do I need a separate `git` repository for each stack?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10312/can-a-single-git-repository-release-multiple-ros-stacks?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-06-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to map git repositories directly onto stacks as you cannot do partial checkouts of git repositories.  For source-based installs using rosinstall, you can get into bad states if you are using more than one stack from a single git repository.  Another way to think of it is, outside of ROS, if you were releasing a software library, you would have a separate repository for that software library, i.e. we generally map releasable units to separate repositories.

You can, however, use git submodules to create larger, virtual repositories.  git submodules are not seamless, but they are the closest to combining the aggregate 'give me everything' behavior of SVN and managing release-able units separately.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just for future reference: The preferred way now seems to be releasing every stack as a separate git repository, then adding them to a rosinstall file and adding that to the indexer. See [this mail](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110816.202545.649d3b91.en.html) by Ken Conley to ros-users. This approach makes it possible to develop and check out each stack separately while avoiding problems with Git submodules (such as [this one](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110816.162454.c32a9704.en.html)).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4